# NServiceBus3 - Upgrading for Environment Specific InputQueues

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, nservicebus

I am looking at upgraded from NServiceBus 2.6 --> 3 and watching the upgrade video, Andreas says you need to use the `EndpointName` attribute.

That is fine, however, what if you have several different environments that use different `InputQueue` names? I have input queues as:

```
MyInputQueue_Dev
MyInputQueue_Stage
MyInputQueue_Prod
```

I need a way to handle this since my messages are environment specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either specify it using the /endpointName:xyz if you're using the host. Or pass in your own func of string.

http://andreasohlund.net/2012/01/27/convention-over-configuration-in-nservicebus-3-0/

That said having the different environments only separated by a convention is usually a bad idea
http://www.udidahan.com/2010/06/05/server-naming-and-configuration-conflicts/

Comment: I presume that if you have multiple instances of NServiceBus running on the same server for multiple environments, then the only way around it is by using the `/endpointName:xyz` parameter when installing the service? I would follow the conventions in this case if we had more than a couple of web servers to host the service.

Comment: That is correct, /servicename + /endpointname is also used to allow running 2 versions of the same service running side by side in zero downtime deployment scenarious